# How do I add a rel to a <a> tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jquery to add a `rel="shadowbox"` to a `<a>` tag

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('a#myid').attr('rel', 'shadowbox');
```